# Finding out the percentage of times a sequence in one column is the same as in another column

Tags: r

I hope I articulate this properly. I have a data set with two columns I am trying to compare in a memory experiment. `Recall.CRESP` is a column specifying the correct answers on a memory test selected through grid coordinates. `Recall.RESP` shows participants response.

The columns look something like this:

```
|Recall.CRESP                     | Recall.RESP                     |
|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|                 
|grid35grid51grid12grid43grid54   | grid35grid51grid12grid43grid54  |                
|grid22grid53grid35grid21grid44   | grid23grid53grid35grid21grid43  |
|grid12grid14grid15grid41grid23   | grid12grid24grid31grid41grid25  |
|grid15grid41grid33grid24grid55   | grid15grid41grid33grid14grid55  |
```

I have the following line of code to tell me the percentage of times per row that the columns are identical to each other:

```
paste0((100*with(Data, mean(Recall.CRESP==Recall.RESP, na.rm = "TRUE"))), "%")
```

So for example, in my dataset 20% of the time column `Recall.CRESP` matches `Recall.RESP` exactly, signifying that a subject scored 5 out of 5 in their memory test 20% of the time.

However I want to be able to expand on this in two ways. The first is rather than giving me a percentage of when the rows are identical, I would like a percentage for when there is a partial match in the sequence. For instance `grid11gird42gird22grid51grid32` and `grid11gird15gird55grid42grid32` share a match of 2/5, with both the first and the last grid coordinate being identical. I am not sure how to specify the request in R for a partial sequence match of 2/5 (or any other outcome out of 5). Also keep in mind that in this example `grid42` shows up in both sequences, but is not correctly recalled considering it is remembered out of position in `Recall.RESP`. The order is important in these sequences.

The other point is that so far I have described the experiment in terms of checking accuracy for forwards recall of memory items. Yet I also have separate data where participants were recalling in backwards order. So for example, `grid11gird22gird33grid44grid55` from `Recall.CRESP` and `grid51grid44grid33grid22grid11` from `Recall.RESP` are correctly matching 4/5 times. How can I turn the code around to check for reverse sequences and calculate percentages out of 5?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate the strings into columns of matrices, which will make them easy to compare and manipulate:

```
# borrowing Oriol's nicely shared data
Recall.CRESP <- c('grid35grid51grid12grid43grid54',
                  'grid22grid53grid35grid21grid44',
                  'grid12grid14grid15grid41grid23',
                  'grid15grid41grid33grid24grid55')

Recall.RESP <- c('grid35grid51grid12grid43grid54',
                 'grid23grid53grid35grid21grid43',
                 'grid12grid24grid31grid41grid25',
                 'grid15grid41grid33grid14grid55')

# function to create matrices
matrixify = function(dat) {
    dat = do.call(rbind, strsplit(dat, split = "grid"))
    dat = dat[, -1]
    mode(dat) = "numeric"
    return(dat)
}

cresp_mat = matrixify(Recall.CRESP)
resp_mat = matrixify(Recall.RESP)

## an example of what we made: just the numbers in the right order
cresp_mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   35   51   12   43   54
# [2,]   22   53   35   21   44
# [3,]   12   14   15   41   23
# [4,]   15   41   33   24   55

## Calculating results is now easy:
(forwards = rowMeans(cresp_mat == resp_mat))
# [1] 1.0 0.6 0.4 0.8

(reverse = rowMeans(cresp_mat == resp_mat[, 5:1]))
# [1] 0.2 0.2 0.0 0.2
```

You could, of course, assign the results to be new columns of your original data.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks you. Might I ask one more thing? How would I come to an overall figure taking into account all of the data. So if for example I wanted to ask what percentage of Recall.CRESP matches Recall.RESP for say 1/5 match?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - Are you asking what percentage of rows score exactly 1/5?

Comment: Exactly, that is what I mean.

Comment: `mean(forwards == 0.2)`

Comment: Perfect. You have saved me a lot of time. I will try and learn from your code for the future. Thanks and all the best.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
Recall.CRESP <- c('grid35grid51grid12grid43grid54',
                  'grid22grid53grid35grid21grid44',
                  'grid12grid14grid15grid41grid23',
                  'grid15grid41grid33grid24grid55')

Recall.RESP <- c('grid35grid51grid12grid43grid54',
                 'grid23grid53grid35grid21grid43',
                 'grid12grid24grid31grid41grid25',
                 'grid15grid41grid33grid14grid55')

df <- data.frame(Recall.CRESP, Recall.RESP, stringsAsFactors = F)
df$correctNormal <- NA
df$correctReverse <- NA

for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  crespVector <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(df[row, 1]), 'grid'))[-1]
  respVector <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(df[row, 2]), 'grid'))[-1]
  correctNormal <- 0
  correctReverse <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(crespVector)) {
    if (crespVector[i] == respVector[i]) correctNormal <- correctNormal + 1
    if (crespVector[i] == respVector[length(respVector) + 1 - i]) correctReverse <- correctReverse + 1
  }
  df$correctNormal[row] = correctNormal / 5
  df$correctReverse[row] = correctReverse / 5
}

df

##                     Recall.CRESP                    Recall.RESP correctNormal correctReverse
## 1 grid35grid51grid12grid43grid54 grid35grid51grid12grid43grid54           1.0            0.2
## 2 grid22grid53grid35grid21grid44 grid23grid53grid35grid21grid43           0.6            0.2
## 3 grid12grid14grid15grid41grid23 grid12grid24grid31grid41grid25           0.4            0.0
## 4 grid15grid41grid33grid24grid55 grid15grid41grid33grid14grid55           0.8            0.2
```